# Want to reuse jQuery function making a function to use again and again

Tags: php, jquery, dry

```
<script>
    // Roti6p20tk
    $(function () {
        $("#distributedPacketForRoti6p20tk, #bonusForRoti6p20tk, " +
            "#replaceForRoti6p20tk, #returnForRoti6p20tk").on("keydown keyup", sumForRoti6p20tk);
        function sumForRoti6p20tk() {
            $("#totalSalePacketForRoti6p20tk").val(Number($("#distributedPacketForRoti6p20tk").val())
                - Number($("#bonusForRoti6p20tk").val()) -
                Number($("#replaceForRoti6p20tk").val()) - Number($("#returnForRoti6p20tk").val())
            );

            $("#salesInAmountForRoti6p20tk").val(Number($("#totalSalePacketForRoti6p20tk").val()) * 20
            );
        }
    });

    // Roti4p14tk
    $(function () {
        $("#distributedPacketForRoti4p14tk, #bonusForRoti4p14tk, " +
            "#replaceForRoti4p14tk, #returnForRoti4p14tk").on("keydown keyup", sumForRoti4p14tk);
        function sumForRoti4p14tk() {
            $("#totalSalePacketForRoti4p14tk").val(Number($("#distributedPacketForRoti4p14tk").val())
                - Number($("#bonusForRoti4p14tk").val()) -
                Number($("#replaceForRoti4p14tk").val())
                - Number($("#returnForRoti4p14tk").val())
            );

            $("#salesInAmountForRoti4p14tk").val(Number($("#totalSalePacketForRoti4p14tk").val()) * 14
            );
        }
    });

    // final sum For Roti
    $(function () {
        $("#extSaleForRoti6p20tk, #extSalesForRoti4p14tk, " +
            " #dueReceivedForRoti, #dueInAmountForRoti, " +
            "#expAndComForRoti").on("keydown keyup", finalsumForRoti);
        function finalsumForRoti() {
            $("#totalSaleAmountForRoti").val(Number($("#extSaleForRoti6p20tk").val())
                + Number($("#extSalesForRoti4p14tk").val()) +
                Number($("#salesInAmountForRoti6p20tk").val())
                + Number($("#salesInAmountForRoti4p14tk").val())
            );

            $("#totalReceivedForRoti").val(Number($("#totalSaleAmountForRoti").val())
                + Number($("#dueReceivedForRoti").val())
                - Number($("#dueInAmountForRoti").val())
                - Number($("#expAndComForRoti").val())
            );
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is the html code

[This is my HTML code With Jquery function](http://ideone.com/YNv8Uk)

I want to reuse these jquery function. I just want to send parameter then this function will do the same work for all.

These above function will do the same as i send parameter. 
How to reuse jquery function without copy paste it again and again?
 Can you show me the way or a tutorial?

I want to reuse the code. I need it more that five times. but i need to copy paste it and change the id or variable but i want to make a function which can do the same. i need to just send the parameter every time . :)

Comment: Javascript runs on client, PHP runs on server: two distinct worlds. So no, you cannot *use* a JavaScript method inside a PHP class.

Comment: @trincot I think he means that PHP is creating the page, and he wants to use a PHP Class to generate the different Javascript functions based on parameters.

Comment: Could be, @Barmar, but rereading the last phrase of the question I cannot help but think the OP expects a JavaScript method to be *reused* by PHP.

Comment: @trincot 
How to reuse jquery function without copy paste it again and again?

Comment: I want to reuse the code. I need it more that five times. but i need to copy paste it and change the id or variable but i want to make a function which can do the same. i need to just send the parameter every time . :)

Comment: I would suggest sharing your HTML so we can see if there is a way you can make this easier by using classes based on how these items are nested.

Comment: @cmorrissey I have given my html code in my description. check it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Javascript function that takes the list of IDs as an argument.

```
function sumForFields(totalid, salesid, inputids, salesmultiplier) {
    $(inputids.join(',')).on("keydown keyup", function() {
        var total = Number($(inputids[0]).val());
        for (var i = 1; i < inputids.length; i++) {
            total -= Number($(inputids[i]).val());
        }
        $(totalid).val(total);
        $(salesid).val(total * salesmultiplier);
    });
}
```

Then you can write:

```
sumForFields('#totalSalePacketForRoti6p20tk', '#salesInAmountForRoti6p20tk', 
            ['#distributedPacketForRoti6p20tk', '#bonusForRoti6p20tk', '#replaceForRoti6p20tk', '#returnForRoti6p20tk'], 
            20);
```

This is for the first two functions. The last one has different structure, since it's mixing addition and subtraction when it combines the fields, not just subtracting everything like the first two.

Comment: upvote - but I would like the OP to share his actual HTML as using IDs may not even be needed depending on how things are nested.

Comment: @Barmar  sumForFields('#totalSalePacketForRoti6p20tk', '#salesInAmountForRoti6p20tk', 
            ['#distributedPacketForRoti6p20tk', '#bonusForRoti6p20tk', '#replaceForRoti6p20tk', '#returnForRoti6p20tk'], 
            20);